# Creating AWS VPC Endpoints with CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-cloudformation

I'm currently looking into automating the creation of [VPC endpoints](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-endpoints.html) within our stack using CloudFormation  (The purpose is so that our stack can access S3 without creating outbound traffic).  The problem is, I can't seem to find any documentation indicating how to declare the resource.  [This page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-vpce-bucketnames.html) seems to be full of warnings about using VPC endpoints with cloudformation, which I'll be sure to heed, but I can't seem to find any documentation on the CFN resource itself.

Comment: Also, if this is in the wrong one of the 500 stack exchange websites, please let me know and I'll re-ask in the right place.

Answer (score 5):

This is what you're looking for:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-vpcendpoint.html

> AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint
>
> The AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint resource creates a VPC endpoint that you can use to establish a private connection between your VPC and another AWS service without requiring access over the Internet, a VPN connection, or AWS Direct Connect.

Quick sample:

```
"S3Enpoint" : {
    "Type" : "AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint",
    "Properties" : {
        "PolicyDocument" : {
            "Version":"2012-10-17",
            "Statement":[{
                "Effect":"Allow",
                "Principal": "*",
                "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
                "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"]
            }]
        },
        "RouteTableIds" : [ {"Ref" : "routetableA"}, {"Ref" : "routetableB"} ],
        "ServiceName" : { "Fn::Join": [ "", [ "com.amazonaws.", { "Ref": "AWS::Region" }, ".s3" ] ] },
        "VpcId" : {"Ref" : "VPCID"}
    }
}
```

Comment: where do you get the route table IDs from?

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint template is not yet available, will probably be published here when ready:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-template-resource-type-ref.html